# MutableMap get's reinitialised when Activity is restarted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am making an app to show Data from firestore in recylerview and on swipe action the data gets removed for user(not from DB) so I created a Map(below my imports) which will keep my keys and array(for recycler view).
Problem is that when user opens the activity and swipe data it gets deleted for user for that lifecycle of app.
When user reopens the app all data is shown in activity(including the one which user had swiped)
I know My code is a bit long but I am new to android dev.
Edits to this qs will be appreciated and thankyou in advance

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.ikgptu.stook.databinding.ActivityNotificationDashboardBinding

var notificationMap : MutableMap<String,NotificationClass> = mutableMapOf()
class NotificationDashboard : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityNotificationDashboardBinding
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    //Array To store and send data to adapter
    private var notificationArray: ArrayList<NotificationClass> = arrayListOf()
    //Views
    private lateinit var myRecylerView: RecyclerView
    //Adapter
    private lateinit var myRecyclerAdapter: MyRecyclerAdapter
    //Collection ID 
    private lateinit var collID: String
    private lateinit var userEmail: String
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityNotificationDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        //Getting Email
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser
        userEmail = currentUser?.email.toString()
        //End
        //Binding View
        myRecylerView = binding.notiRecylerView
        //Getting ID
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("users").document(userEmail).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                    if (document != null) {
                        Log.d("Found", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.getString("collectionID")}")
                        collID = document.getString("collectionID").toString()
                        searchFireStore()
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Wrong", "No such document")
                    }
                }
        //Specifying Drag Direction
        ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val deletedCourse: NotificationClass = notificationArray[viewHolder.adapterPosition]
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val documentID = notificationArray[position].docID
                notificationMap[documentID]!!.status = false
                notificationArray = arrayListOf()
                for(key in notificationMap.keys){
                    if(notificationMap[key]!!.status){
                        notificationArray.add(notificationMap[key]!!)
                    }
                }
                myRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                Snackbar.make(myRecylerView, deletedCourse.title.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("Undo") { // adding on click listener to our action of snack bar.

                    notificationMap[documentID]!!.status = true
                    notificationArray = arrayListOf()
                    for (key in notificationMap.keys) {
                        if (notificationMap[key]!!.status) {
                            notificationArray.add(notificationMap[key]!!)
                        }
                    }
                    myRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position)
                }.show()
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(myRecylerView)
        
     }
    private fun searchFireStore(){
        //Firestore Search
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection(collID).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        for (document in task.result!!) {
                            Log.d("Start", document.id + " => " + document.data)
                            val notification = NotificationClass(document.data["Title"] as String?, document.data["Notification"] as String?,true,document.id)
                            if(!notificationMap.containsKey(document.id)){
                                notificationMap[document.id] = notification
                            }
                            Log.d("Success", "Documents fetched successfully")
                        }
                        for(key in notificationMap.keys){
                            if(notificationMap.get(key)?.status == true){
                                notificationArray.add(notificationMap[key]!!)
                            }
                        }
                        myRecylerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                        myRecyclerAdapter = MyRecyclerAdapter(notificationArray)
                        myRecylerView.adapter = myRecyclerAdapter
                        myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                        Log.d("FOR", "Success of FOR LOOP") 
                    } 
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you 'kill' your app and then open it again, then `onCreate()` function for Activity is called again, and your app is doing exactly the same as during first launch. If you want your app to not show swiped items, you have to persist somehow the information, which elements were swipped and use it during next Activity creation to exclude swipped elements from list.

Comment: But qs is how to implement that

Comment: You could for example add swiped elements indexes (or other primary keys) to some list and save it in SharedPreferences in `onDestroy()`. Then retrieve this list from SharedPreferences in `onCreate()` and remove the elements from RecyclerView.